# Generate html table with multiple row headers using DataTable (ASP.NET MVC Web Application)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, web, datatable

i have this method to cast my `DataTable` object to an `html string`:

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4]
{
                new DataColumn("Descrizione investimento",typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Data effettuazione",typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Importo",typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Caratteristiche operative",typeof(string)),
});

foreach (FinanziamentoDaTerziResultModel finanziamentoDaTerzi in finanziamentiDaTerziResults)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(finanziamentoDaTerzi.Descrizione, finanziamentoDaTerzi.Data_Erogazione.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), finanziamentoDaTerzi.Importo.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), "Testo");
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// Table start
sb.Append("<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;font-size: 9pt;font-family:Arial' width='100%'>");

// adding HeaderRow
sb.Append("<tr>");
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    sb.Append("<th style='height: 30px;background-color: #ffffff;border-top: 1px solid #a5a5a5;border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5;color: #000000;font-weight: bold;'>").Append(column.ColumnName).Append("</th>");
}

sb.Append("</tr>");

// adding DataRow
int index = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string trColor;
    if (index == 0)
        trColor = "#ededed";
    else
        trColor = "#ffffff";

    sb.Append("<tr style='background-color: ").Append(trColor).Append(";height: 35px;'>");
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        sb.Append("<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid #ccc;'>").Append(row[column.ColumnName].ToString()).Append("</td>");
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");

    if (index == 0)
        index = 1;
    else
        index = 0;
}

// Table end
sb.Append("</table>");

return sb.ToString();
```

It works correctly now, but I need to create a table that has parent columns in which there must be sub-columns referring to the element defined in the parent column.

This is an example of what it should look like:

```
+----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|Name      |Year 1                          |Year 2                          |
|          |----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|          |1st Term  |2nd Term  |3rd Term  |1st Term  |2nd Term  |3rd Term  |    
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Name1     |XX        |YY        |ZZ        |XX        |YY        |ZZ        |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Name2     |YY        |ZZ        |XX        |YY        |ZZ        |XX        |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Is it possible to achieve this by using DataTable objects? And if so how can I do?

(note this is a web application, not a desktop app so i'haven't gridview or other `Window.Forms` tools)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

using just my `data objects` and the `StringBuilder`, so i didn't use the `DataTable objects`:

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<int> anni = servizi.RangeAnniContratto;

sb.Append("<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;font-size: 9pt;font-family:Arial' width='100%'>");

sb.Append("<tr>");
sb.Append("<th rowspan='2' style='height: 30px;background-color: #ffffff;border-top: 1px solid #a5a5a5;border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5;color: #000000;font-weight: bold;'>Attività di servizio</th>");
for (int i = 0; i < anni.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append("<th colspan='3' style='height: 30px;background-color: #ffffff;border-top: 1px solid #a5a5a5;border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5;color: #000000;font-weight: bold;'>").Append(anni[i]).Append("</th>");
}
sb.Append("</tr>");
sb.Append("<tr>");
for (int i = 0; i < anni.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append("<td>Corrispettivi attesi annui</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>Costi diretti del servizio</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>Margine operativo lordo</td>");
}
sb.Append("</tr>");

int index = 0;
List<ContrattoResultModel> contratti = servizi.Contratti;
foreach (ContrattoResultModel contr in contratti)
{
    string trColor;
    if (index == 0)
        trColor = "#ededed";
    else
        trColor = "#ffffff";

    CONTRATTO c = contr.Contratto;
    List<CONTRATTO_RIGHE> cr = c.CONTRATTO_RIGHE.ToList();
    List<MATERIALE_SERVIZIO_ESTERNO> materiali = contr.MaterialiServiziContratto;

    sb.Append("<tr style='background-color: ").Append(trColor).Append(";height: 35px;'>");
    sb.Append("<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid #ccc;'>");
    sb.Append(c.CONTRATTO_COMMESSA.Descrizione);
    sb.Append("</td>");
    for (int i = 0; i < anni.Count; i++)
    {
        List<decimal> ricServList = cr.Where(x => x.Anno_Riferimento.Year == anni[i]).Select(s => s.Importo_Corrispettivo).ToList();
        decimal ricServ = ricServList.Sum();
        sb.Append("<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid #ccc;'>");
        sb.Append(ricServ.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
        sb.Append("</td>");

        ICollection<MATERIALE_SERVIZIO_ESTERNO_RIGHE> im = materiali.Where(x => x.MATERIALE_SERVIZIO_ESTERNO_RIGHE.Any(a => a.Anno_Riferimento.Year == anni[i])).Select(s => s.MATERIALE_SERVIZIO_ESTERNO_RIGHE).FirstOrDefault();
        List<decimal> costDirServList = im.Where(x => x.Anno_Riferimento.Year == anni[i]).Select(s => s.Importo).ToList();
        decimal costDirServ = costDirServList.Sum();
        sb.Append("<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid #ccc;'>");
        sb.Append(costDirServ.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
        sb.Append("</td>");

        string margOpLo = (ricServ - costDirServ).ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        sb.Append("<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid #ccc;'>");
        sb.Append(margOpLo);
        sb.Append("</td>");
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");

    if (index == 0)
        index = 1;
    else
        index = 0;
}

sb.Append("</table>");
```

This is the rendered result over the client:
[image: rendered table]